# my wireless card does not work

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

Everything was working just fine until I followed the instructions [here](http://forum.aircrack-ng.org/index.php?topic=314.0). Now the driver seems to be there but for some unknown reason the wireless card cannot connect to any network.

```
lspci | grep Network

Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe
Wireless Network Adapter
```

here is the results of running `iwconfig`:

```
iwconfig

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"SSID-E5172-DC7B"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Tx-Power=20 dBm
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
```

I was thinking, when I first installed ubuntu 13.04, ubuntu automatically installed the right network drivers. So, can I make it do that without having to reinstall it again??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have had the same problem and you can use the terminal and type:

```
   rfkill list
   lspci
   lsmod wlan0
   nmap -v -iR 10000 -pN www.google.com
```

it sould work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Aircrack disables your WiFi card for normal usage. To reenable it, have a look at [this question](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1856771) asked on ubuntuforums.org

Comment: I tried all the solutions in this post ,but with no luck